# Which version of php added anonymous functions

Tags: php, anonymous-function

In manual there is `create_function` function and you can pass result from that function to `array_map`, I thought that that is the only way to have something like anonymous functions and closures, but then I found that I can just put function like in javascript

```
array_map(function($a) {
    return $a + 1;
}, array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5));
```

In which version of php I can do this? Was this always there?

Comment: I just RTFM but still was not pretty sure, so this question clarified

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Closures ([anonymous functions](http://uk.php.net/functions.anonymous)) were added in PHP 5.3.0, including the `use` clause.

---

Then since PHP 5.4.0 the `static` keyword is supported in front of it to denote a static function.

And as of PHP 7.4.0  *[arrow functions](http://uk.php.net/functions.arrow) ([RFC](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/arrow_functions_v2))* as a more concise syntax.

Comment: Thanks, I have seen that page but I didn't notice the version number.

Comment: In the "Changelog" section of the page, after the examples

Comment: Yes I found it, I just explain why I didn't notice it before I read your answer.

Comment: The changelog no longer shows when they were added.

Answer (score 5):

[Anonymous functions](http://php.net/functions.anonymous) are available since [PHP 5.3](http://php.net/releases/5_3_0.php):

> **The key features of PHP 5.3.0 include:**
>
> - …
> - [Lambda Functions and Closures](http://php.net/closures)
> - …

Answer (score 1):

PHP >5.3:

http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php

Comment: You said php > 5.3 but according to documentation it is >= 5.3 .