# Use a local variable in preg_replace_callback - PHP

Tags: php, preg-replace-callback

How to use a local variable in `preg_replace_callback` in PHP.
I have the following code:

```
function pregRep($matches)
{
    global $i; $i++;

    if($i > 2)
    {     
          return '#'.$matches[0];
    }
    else
    {
        return $matches[0];
    }
}

$i = 0;
$str =  preg_replace_callback($reg_exp,"pregRep",$str);
```

And also `$str` is a string, `$reg_exp` is a regex expression. Both of these are well defined.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Use of `global` keyword is, in general, a [code smell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell).

Answer (score 9):

The easiest way is with an [anonymous function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9148841/which-version-of-php-added-anonymous-functions) as callback:

```
$result = preg_replace_callback(
    $pattern,

    function ($match) use ($variable) {
        // do something
    },

    $subject
);
```

Note that you can add multiple variables in this way, but it will create a copy of that variable as it is when the function is defined (this is important if you are assigning it to a variable for multiple uses). If you want a "live" reference to the variable, use `&$variable`.

Of course, using arrow functions instead requires PHP 7.4 or newer.