# How to know the match count in preg_replace_callback - PHP

Tags: php, preg-replace-callback

I have this code in php -:

```
function pregRepler($matches)
{
    * do something
}

$str = preg_replace_callback($reg_exp,'pregRepler',$str);
```

When in function `pregRepler`, i would want to know the current `match number` like if it is the first match or the second or anything...

How do i do it.??

Comment: I know its an old question but since PHP 5.1.0 a "count" variable has been added. You can use it to get the count. `preg_replace_callback ($regex, callback_function, $subject, $limit, &$count)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
function pregRepler($matches) {
    static $matchcount = 0;
    // do stuff
    $matchcount++;
}
```

This works better with an anonymous function, as I mentioned in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15934350/507674) to [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15934249/use-a-local-variable-in-preg-replace-callback-php), as this will avoid problems if you have multiple calls to `preg_replace_callback`.

Comment: @Kolink shouldn't you define the static outside the function? Will this not reset $matchcount to 0 on every call?

Comment: @nl-x No, the variable is static, so it will only be defined and initialized once.

Comment: @M8R-1jmw5r That counts the total for use outside the callback, not the running count inside it.

Comment: @RayZ If my answers helped you, please consider marking them as Accepted by clicking the check mark under the post's score.

Answer (score 2):

You need to share a `$count` variable between both variable scopes, for example by using a variable alias:

```
$callback = function($matches) use (&$count) {
    $count++;
    return sprintf("<%d:%s>", $count, $matches[0]);
};

echo preg_replace_callback($pattern, $callback , $subject, $limit = -1, $count);
```

Before invoking, `$count` is equal to 0. After invoking `$count` is set to the number of replacements done. In between you can count up in your callback. You can also set to zero again when calling another time.

[See it in action](http://eval.in/15896)

See http://php.net/preg_replace_callback

Answer (score 0):

```
$repled     = 0;
function pregRepler($matches)
{
    * do something
    global $repled;
    $repled++;
}

$str = preg_replace_callback($reg_exp,'pregRepler',$str);
```

Just count from a global variable.