# PHP: Removing duplicate words from between quotes

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

How can I remove the duplicates from between class="" in the following string?

```
<li class="active active"><a href="http://netcoding.net/indev/sample-page/">Sample Page</a></li>
```

Please note that the classes shown can change and be in different positions.

Comment: The real problem to solve is why you have duplicates in the first place!

Comment: So this is *almost certainly* not going to be possible with Regex. You are really going to have to *parse* this string.

Comment: The OP is a classic example of the "XY Problem":  http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/157574

Comment: You're not looking to "remove duplicate words from between quotes".  You want to "remove duplicate words from the class attribute of an HTML <li> tag".  You'll want to use a DOM parser.

Comment: What @Sparky said. Please don't try and solve a symptom, solve the underlying problem instead.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use DOM parser then `explode` and `array_unique`:

```
$html = '<li class="active active">
         <a href="http://netcoding.net/indev/sample-page/">Sample Page</a></li>';
$doc = new DOMDocument();
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$doc->loadHTML($html); // loads your html
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$nodelist = $xpath->query("//li");
for($i=0; $i < $nodelist->length; $i++) {
    $node = $nodelist->item($i);
    $tok = explode(' ', $node->getAttribute('class'));
    $tok = array_unique($tok);
    $node->setAttribute('class', implode(' ', $tok));
}
$html = $doc->saveHTML();
echo $html;
```

#### OUTPUT:

```
<html><body>
<li class="active"><a href="http://netcoding.net/indev/sample-page/">Sample Page</a></li>
</body></html>
```

#### [Online Demo](https://eval.in/130904)

Comment: This is the first time I see you answer with DOM :) +1

Comment: lol :) I am not a PHP programmer by profession but I have answered many using DOM in the past.

Comment: This leaves empty class attributes.

Comment: @BrianGraham,  Seems like preventing the duplicates in the first place would be far less work.

Comment: @BrianGraham, Nope see the demo here https://eval.in/130904 The code works perfect.

Comment: @BrianGraham I have attached generated output also which has one "active"

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran: Thanks so much for your demo link, I took the liberty to include it in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

With regex you could use a lookbehind and lookahead for finding duplicates:

```
$pattern = '/(?<=class=")(?:([-\w]+) (?=\1[ "]))+/i';
```

This would replace multiple instances of capture group 1 `([-\w]+)` in a sequence.

```
$str = '<li class="active active">';

echo preg_replace($pattern, "", $str);
```

*output*:

```
<li class="active">
```

[Test at regex101](http://regex101.com/r/oQ0qN7/2)

---

**EDIT 08.04.2014**

To remove duplicates, that are not directly after the lookbehind `(?<=class=")`...

The problem is, that a lookbehind assertion can only be of fixed length. so something like `(?<=class="[^"]*?)` is not possible. As an alternative [\K could be used](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-php.html#k), which resets the beginning of the match. A pattern could be:

```
$pattern = '/class="[^"]*?\K(?<=[ "])(?:([-\w]+) (?=\1[ "]))+/i';
```

You could imagine everything before `\K` as a virtual lookbehind of variable length.

This regex, as the first one, would only replace multiple instances of one duplicate in a sequence.

---

**EDIT 11.09.2014**

Finally I think a single regex, that would strip out all of different duplicates is getting rather complex:

```
/(?>(?<=class=")|(?!^)\G)(?>\b([-\w]++)\b(?=[^"]*?\s\1[\s"])\s+|[-\w]+\s+\K)/
```

This one uses [continuous matching](http://www.regular-expressions.info/continue.html), as soon `class="` is found.

[Test at regex101](http://regex101.com/r/uY8kW5/1); Also see [SO Regex FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean/22944075#22944075)

A more simple way using regex would be a [preg_replace_callback()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php):

```
$html = '<li class="a1 a1 li li-home active li li active a1">';

$html = preg_replace_callback('/\sclass="\K[^"]+/', function ($m) {
  return trim(implode(" ",array_unique(preg_split('~\s+~', $m[0]))));
}, $html);
```

Note that [older PHP-versions don't support anonymous functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9148841/which-version-of-php-add-anonymous-functions) (if so, change to a normal function).

Comment: How can I modify this so that it works with `li li-home active active`. It's stripping my `li`, and not any other repeating terms.

Comment: Hey @BrianGraham, see my updated answer. Also added a hyphen to the allowed classname characters `[-\w]` and `[ "]` as boundaries.

Answer (score 1):

A way to do it would be to add these values into an array and to filter them. Here is how it can be made.

```
<?php
   preg_match_all('/class="([A-Za-z0-9 ]+)"/',$htmlString, $result);
   $classes = explode(" ",$result[0]);
   $classes = array_unique($classes);
   echo "<li class=\"".implode(" ",$classes)."\"><a href=\"http://netcoding.net/indev/sample-page/\">Sample Page</a></li>";
?>
```