# Alternative of "use" in older PHP version

Tags: php, closures, anonymous-function

Anonymous function can be used as callback for function eg. `array_map` and one of its advantage is usage of `use` to use a variable from outside of the function. Eg.:

```
$var = 10;
$x = array_map(function($e) use ($var) { if($var > 5) return $e['prop']; }, $myArray);
```

What about in older PHP version when callback has to be an existing function and function eg. `array_map` receives the function name as callback argument?

```
$var = 10;
$x = array_map("myFunction", $myArray);

function myFunction($e) {
    //how to get $var here?
}
```

Please keep in mind that I'm looking for solution other than using `global` variable. Thanks.

Comment: but what are you actual trying to achieve?

Comment: I would use `$GLOBALS['var']`. `$GLOBALS` is a superglobal variable (like `$_GET` or `$_POST`), therefore available from every function. Each variable is an index in this superglobal.

Comment: @Dagon: I'd like to achieve the same like using anonymous function with `use`, but in older PHP which doesn't support anonymous function.

Answer (score 1):

Probably a dumb way to do it, but you could use an overloaded class with a static variable (so kind of like a global...). I only suggest overloading because it works like a regular variable (in how you assign it).

I'm sure someone who has worked with PHP longer than I have will have a better idea. Also I am not sure what "older version" means *(how old "old" is)* but the overloading goes back to at least 5.0/5.1. I think the closure is around 5.3 (according to this answer [Which version of php add anonymous functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9148841/which-version-of-php-add-anonymous-functions))? This is not *exactly* the scenario, you have outlined, but the accessing of the value is made available without using a true `global`:

```
class Overlord
    {
        private static  $properties;
        public  static  $val;

        public  function __get($property)
            {
                return (isset(self::$properties[$property]))? self::$properties[$property]:false;
            }

        public  function __set($property,$value)
            {
                self::$val  =   self::$properties[$property]    =   $value;
            }

        public  function __isset($property)
            {
                return  (isset(self::$properties[$property]));          
            }
    }

function myFunction($e) {
    return Overlord::$val." overloaded PLUS -->".$e;
}

// Create the mighty overloader class
$ov         =   new Overlord();
// Assign a variable
$ov->val    =   21;
// Random well-thought-out array
$myArray    =   array("One",1,"Two",2);
// Run through the first variable
$x = array_map("myFunction", $myArray);
// Assign a second random variable
$ov->stuff  =   11;
// Run through the array again with new variable
$y = array_map("myFunction", $myArray);
// Array one
print_r($x);
// Array two
print_r($y);
```

Would give you something like:

```
   Array
(
    [0] => 21 overloaded PLUS -->One
    [1] => 21 overloaded PLUS -->1
    [2] => 21 overloaded PLUS -->Two
    [3] => 21 overloaded PLUS -->2
)
Array
(
    [0] => 11 overloaded PLUS -->One
    [1] => 11 overloaded PLUS -->1
    [2] => 11 overloaded PLUS -->Two
    [3] => 11 overloaded PLUS -->2
)
```

Comment: Nice idea, using class with static variable.